# How to make Express.js log errors during asynchronous operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, error-handling

I have code like this:

```
exports.listSavedThreads = function (req, res) {
  SavedThread.find({}).exec().then(function (data) {
    wat.map();
    res.render('home/listSavedThreads');
  });
};
```

`wat` is undefined variable, so the code above doesn't work and `res.render()` is never called, but nothing is being printed to the console, it fails silently and browser is stuck in an endless loading.

If I do the same without a promise:

```
exports.listSavedThreads = function (req, res) {
  wat.map();
  res.render('home/listSavedThreads');
};
```

The error is being printed to the console and the browser, as usual.

The only way I've been able to print an error is by using `try/catch`:

```
exports.listSavedThreads = function (req, res) {
  SavedThread.find({}).exec().then(function (data) {
    try {
      wat.map();
      res.render('home/listSavedThreads');
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('Error: ', e);
    }
  });
};
```

Then in the console I see:

`Error:  [ReferenceError: wat is not defined]`

Obviously, I can't put `try/catch` into every operation, because I mostly need error output for development, so I can see my typos and stuff like that. Is there a way to output errors for all operations, even asynchronous one?

Comment: You are using the try/catch correctly.  If your design requires you to write the same code over and over, you might consider a functional breakdown or if you dig OO, using polymorphism might clean it up too.

Comment: @NathanielJohnson, putting `try/catch` in every async function I ever write is a bit of overhead, If all I need is error logging. Browsers print errors inside promises just fine, so why can't Node? I think, something might be wrong with my configuration, but I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when doing async calls not using Promises, it is common/best practice to use [error-first callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) to ensure that errors are communicated & handled appropriately. This is the most common approach and is used heavily in libraries like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Since you're using a Promise in your code snippet I'll provide an approach to error handling using Promises. One of the best reasons to use Promises is because they offer great exception handling out of the box.

Add a `.catch()` call into your Promise chain. Any error that occurs within your promise will propagate out to the nearest `.catch()` handler. `.catch()` is an alternative to providing an `onRejected` callback function in your `.then()`.

[MDN Promise `.catch()` Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

[Bluebird.js - Why Promises?](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-promises.html) has some examples of the benefits of error handling when using Promises.

```
exports.listSavedThreads = function (req, res) {
  SavedThread.find({})
    .exec()
    .then(function (data) {
      wat.map();
      res.render('home/listSavedThreads');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      //handle errors
    });
};
```

Alternatively, you could just check if `wat` is defined before continuing and handling that scenario accordingly.

```
exports.listSavedThreads = function (req, res) {
  SavedThread.find({})
    .exec()
    .then(function (data) {
      if(wat) {
        wat.map();
        return res.render('home/listSavedThreads');
      }
      else {
        // Handle wat undefined
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but, as I said, I only need for development, so I can save time on finding typos or obvious logic errors. Adding `.catch()` to every promise I ever make in my application wouldn't help me much in terms of saving time. I suppose, I can use something like eslint for that, but it seems strange that Node.js can not print errors that occur in promises by default. Browsers can do it just fine.